# Conflict between spring data jpa and spring data DynamoDB

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, amazon-dynamodb

I am working in a project where I want to use 2 different repositories. 
The first one is a spring data JPA repository and the second one a DynamoDB repository.

I have created two different configuration classes for the respective data sources with two different repository Interfaces in different packages.

When I try to run the project I get the above error message :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException:
>   Invalid bean definition with name 'personDynamoRepository' defined in
>   null: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class
>   [org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBRepositoryFactoryBean];
>   scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0;
>   dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
>   factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null;
>   destroyMethodName=null] for bean 'campaignDynamoRepository': There is
>   already [Root bean: class
>   [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean];
>   scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0;
>   dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
>   factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null;
>   destroyMethodName=null] bound.

what I get a form that is that spring data DynamoDB has a conflict with spring data jpa.

Is there a way through this ?

Comment: Did you try defining both beans explicitly with qualifiers on them?

Comment: @SyedSirajUddin no. Do you have a reference to check how I can do that?

Comment: @SyedSirajUddin although I do not think that it will work. It seems that when the spring container is initialised It creates the personDynamoDbRepo as a Jpa repo and then it tries to create another personDynamoDbRepo as a dynamoDb repo. (from what I get from the error message) And I am wondered why is this happening. the dynamoDbrepo should not be take in consideration from the jpabeanfactory.. (I jave not a lot of experience as you can see )

Comment: Sure, you could to your config class just add two beans like:  [main]  @Qualifier("Dynamo")
    public DynamoDBRepositoryFactoryBean dynamoFactorybean(){
        return new DynamoDBRepositoryFactoryBean();
    }
    @Qualifier("Jpa")
    public JpaRepositoryFactoryBean jpaFactorybean(){
        return new JpaRepositoryFactoryBean();
    }[main]

Comment: just add @Bean to both in the above code.

Comment: I have two different config classes for each repo. And the config class for the dynamoDb is ion another submodule as well. You think this will still work?

Comment: yes, as long as you declare them explicitly, you may have other problems after that which you might have to fix.

Comment: @SyedSirajUddin I manage to found a sollution I posted it bellow. Thank you very much for your help